# How to show laravel login throttle message at the top of the page?

Tags: php, laravel-5, web-frameworks, vs-web-site-project

By default Laravel shows throttling message "Too many login attempts" message below email/username field.

How to display this message at top of the page.

Comment: just go to ```login.blade.php``` and move the error showing code to top of the page

Comment: But i want to show ValidationError message below each. Just want to show "wrong credentials and too many login attempts at top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `sendLockoutResponse` in your `LoginController

```
protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request)
{
    $seconds = $this->limiter()->availableIn(
        $this->throttleKey($request)
    );

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'throttle' => [Lang::get('auth.throttle', ['seconds' => $seconds])],
    ])->status(Response::HTTP_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
}
```

You need to import following

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

Then in your view add the following where you need the throttled message

If your Laravel version is `5.8.12` or newer

```
@error('throttle')
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
@enderror
```

else

```
@if ($errors->has('throttle'))
    <strong>{{ $errors->first('throttle') }}</strong>
@endif
```

Comment: It shows class "app\http\controllers\auth\Lang" not found

Comment: you need to import following`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;`,  `use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;`, `use Illuminate\Http\Response`

Comment: I am a beginner. Thanks for the help. By the way is this the proper and easy way to customize.

Comment: Yes in most cases if you want to customize the default behavior of framework provided boilerplate you need to either override a method or change/override a property

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot. Learned something new.